# Trouble with JSON and the Twitter API

Tags: python, json, twitter

So, i'm running into this problem while trying to request statuses from my feed and the error is so vague I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

```
My Code:

with open("Output.txt") as input:
lines = [line for line in input if line.strip()]

with open("Output.txt", "w") as output:
    for items in api.request('statuses/home_timeline', {'count': '200'}):
        x = ((items['text'] if 'text' in items else items).encode('ascii', 'ignore'))
        current_id = id(x)
        print(current_id)
        print(x.decode('ascii', 'ignore'))
        output.write((x.decode('ascii', 'ignore')) + '\n')
    for items in api.request('statuses/home_timeline', {'count': '200'}, {'max_id': str(current_id)}):
        x = ((items['text'] if 'text' in items else items).encode('ascii', 'ignore'))
        current_id = id(x)
        print(current_id)
        print(x.decode('ascii', 'ignore'))
        output.write((x.decode('ascii', 'ignore')) + '\n')




The Error Code returned:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Brandon/PycharmProjects/untitled/automated_timeline_collector.py", line 29, in <module>
    for items in api.request('statuses/home_timeline', {'count': '200'}, {'max_id': str(current_id)}):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\TwitterAPI\TwitterAPI.py", line 140, in __iter__
    for item in self.get_iterator():
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\TwitterAPI\TwitterAPI.py", line 137, in get_iterator
    return RestIterator(self.response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\TwitterAPI\TwitterAPI.py", line 165, in __init__
    resp = response.json()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 756, in json
    return json.loads(self.content.decode(encoding), **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\__init__.py", line 338, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 366, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 384, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded

Process finished with exit code 1
```

The program gets through the first 200 statuses no problem but something about the way I am using the current id to let the code pick up where it left off is not quite right. Thanks for the help and feedback.

Comment: So if what you're getting back isn't JSON then just what **is** it?

Comment: catch the exception and see if it has more details. it could be normal to hit some bad pages, catch the exception and continue.

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
for items in api.request('statuses/home_timeline', {'count': '200'}):
```

To this:

```
for items in api.request('statuses/home_timeline', {'count': '200'}).get_iterator():
```

Answer (score 0):

1. No JSON object could be decoded
   there is illegal character in your data which JSON can not decode or encode;
2. A little but very significant suggestion: Do not use some sensible names as your variables, when I find that you use "input" as your variable, though not that sure, but I type sth below:

[image]